# Convergence of infinite product in valued field

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

This is an problem from Borevich&Shaferevich book Number Theory, problem 17, Chapter 4, Section 1:

Let $k$ be a complete valued field with discrete valuation $\nu$. Show the infinite product $\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1+a_n)$, $a_n\ne -1$ converges if and only if $a_n\to 0$.

I can show if $a_n\to0$, then the infinite product converges. But I have difficulty in seeing why the converse is even true. Let $a_n=-1+\pi$ where $\pi$ is the uniformizer, isn't it true that the valuation of the infinite product will goes to infinity, which shows the product converges to $0$? Because
$\nu(\prod_{n=1}^N(1+a_n))=\sum_{n=1}^N\nu(\pi)=N\to \infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that in this context, an infinite product is said to "converge" if it converges to a *nonzero* value.  Without this proviso, the statement is indeed incorrect as your example demonstrates.

To prove it, suppose $\prod(1+a_n)$ converges to some limit $L\neq 0$.  Let $p_N=\prod_1^N(1+a_n)$, so $p_N\to L$.  In particular, for sufficiently large $N$, $\nu(p_N)=\nu(L)<\infty$ (since $L\neq 0$), and $p_{N+1}-p_N\to 0$.  But $p_{N+1}-p_N=a_Np_N$, and since the valuation of $p_N$ is eventually constant and finite, the only way this can go to $0$ is if the valuation of $a_N$ goes to $\infty$.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thank you!

Comment: A side note: can we just use completeness to say since $p_N$ is convergent so it is Cauchy and thus $p_{N+1}-p_N\to 0$?

Comment: Completeness is irrelevant.  A convergent sequence is always Cauchy in any metric space.